# Different targets on Different OS with Ant

Tags: ant

I have an ant target I don't want called unless I am running ant on Linux  (Not called on Windows)

```
<target name="jar.all" depends="clean,compile.nic,jar,jar.resources"/>
```

The target that I don't want called on Windows is: **compile.nic**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Insert an if property to your compile.nic target.

```
<target name="compile.nic" if="windowsos">
```

And use this conditions before running your target

```
<condition property="windowsos">
  <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<condition property="linuxos">
  <os family="unix" />
</condition>
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a real-world example for Windows vs. UNIX commands. The ELSE improves on previous answers.

```
<condition property="maven.executable" value="mvn.bat" else="mvn">
  <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<target name="clean">
  <exec executable="${maven.executable}">
    <arg value="clean" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: I thought you could just run "mvn" and Windows would silently append the .bat for you. Did Ant somehow cripple this behaviour? :/

Comment: Yes, the windows behavior is a little different with <exec>:  "The <exec> task delegates to Runtime.exec which in turn apparently calls ::CreateProcess. It is the latter Win32 function that defines the exact semantics of the call. In particular, if you do not put a file extension on the executable, only ".EXE" files are looked for, not ".COM", ".CMD" or other file types listed in the environment variable PATHEXT. That is only used by the shell." -- https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Answer (score 8):

[Can I make the Ant copy task OS-specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86526/ant-os-specific-copy-task)

Additionally some tasks support `os` attribute. for example exec:

```
<exec executable="cmd" os="windows"/>
```

Comment: In Ant 1.7 and up, exec supports the "osfamily" attribute, which is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` condition to set a property, and then skip your target by adding either the `if` or `unless` attributes (depending on how you define your property)